# Image taken from camera won't upload to firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a button which presents the choice to user whether he wants the image from gallery or camera. When user takes image from gallery I am able to successfully upload the image to firebase storage, but when user chooses camera, I am not able to upload the image to storage.
Here is my onActivityResult code when user chooses camera

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            selectedImageUri =Uri.parse(data.getExtras().get("data").toString()) ;
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            cameraImageButton.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
```

It uploads the image to my imageview, but gives me error saying

```
No content provider: android.graphics.Bitmap@1b9dbf5f
                                                                                 java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: android.graphics.Bitmap@1b9dbf5f
```

When I try to upload to storage

I have gone through a [similar question posted on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376328/capturing-image-from-camera-and-upload-to-firebase).

I think the accepted answer is wrong because if I use

```
mImageUri = data.getData();
            mSelectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);
```

The above code is only right when you take image from gallery. The image is never uploaded to my imageview if I use above code and take camera image so I am not able to push it to firebase storage. Please help

Comment: Got it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710599/image-capture-with-camera-upload-to-firebase-uri-in-onactivityresult-is-nul

Answer (score 0):

When the camera button is been clicked use the following code:

```
int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        String imgFileName = "image_name".jpg";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        String pictureImagePath = storageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + imgFileName;
        File file = new File(pictureImagePath);

        Uri outputFileUri;
        if(version < 24){

            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        } else {

            outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
                    file);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 111);
```

In the onActivityResult method use the following code:

```
String imgFileName = "image_name".jpg";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        String pictureImagePath = storageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + imgFileName;
        File imgFile = new  File(pictureImagePath);

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

        byte[] dataArray = bytes.toByteArray();
```

Comment: where have you defined dataArray of this.dataArray?

Comment: I ignored the line but the image does not get pushed to firebase